# Altering attributes in another class in Python

Tags: python-3.x, class, attributes

I have been trying to alter a list in class Inventory from class Pod, but I get an error that I am popping from an empty set.  Is there anyway that I can pop from a list from an Inventory instance that I know is populated?  Essentially, I am trying to transfer widgets from Inventory to Pod.

```
class Widget():

    def __init__(self):
        self.cost = 6
        self.value = 9


class Inventory():

    def __init__(self):
        self.widgets_inv = []
        self.cost_inv = 0
        self.value_inv = 0

    def buy_inv(self):
        x = int(input("How many widgets to you want to add to inventory? "))
        for i in range(0, x):
            self.widgets_inv.append(Widget())

    def get_inv(self):
        print("You have " + str(len(self.widgets_inv)) + " widgets in inventory.")

    def cost_of_inv(self):
        cost_inv = len(self.widgets_inv) * Widget().cost
        print("The current cost of your inventory is: " + cost_inv + " USD.")

    def value_of_inv(self):
        val_inv = len(self.widgets_inv) * Widget().value
        print("The current value of your inventory is: " + val_inv + " USD.")

class Pod():
    """A pod is a grouping of several widgets.  Widgets are sold in pods"""

    def __init__(self):
        self.pod = []

    def creat_pod(self):
        x = int(input("How many widgets would you like to place in this pod? "))
        for i in range(0, x):
            self.pod.append(Widget())
            Inventory().widgets_inv.pop()
```

Comment: Please include the error-message in your question. Please let us know on which line the error occurs. May be on the last line ?

Comment: Sorry about that.

Comment: ---> 41             Inventory().widgets_inv.pop()

IndexError: pop from empty list

Comment: One way to prevent this error is to check whether there any elements in list widgets_inv.  The number of entries can be fetched by calling *len* . Use an if-statement to check whether it is not 0. Only if not 0 use *pop*.

Comment: I think I know the problem, but I cannot figure out an answer.  I believe the problem is that when I call Inventory() in Pod() it creates a new instance for Inventory().  Is there any way I can call a specific instance in Inventory() from Pod() that I know already has a populated list?  -Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You should modify the *creat_pod*-method, so that you can handover the Inventory-object. This allows you to add widgets to the inventory-object before calling *creat_pod*-method:

```
def creat_pod(self, inventory):
        x = int(input("How many widgets would you like to place in this pod? "))
        for i in range(0, x):
            self.pod.append(Widget())
            inventory.widgets_inv.pop()
```

In your original code you create always a new Inventory-object, which has therefore and empty widget-list:

```
Inventory().widgets_inv.pop()
```

Comment: Thanks Aedvald, one question, the 'inventory' that you have included as an argument, does that refer to the class or the instance?  Same question for the final line.